# How to click on an element from the Dropdown menu through Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on the drop down menu but with no luck .
the menu is activated by javascript .
I tried to click on the link inside the parent div but nothing happens 
here is some code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.energisa.com.br/Paginas/login.aspx")
select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlEstado'))
select_element.select_by_value('MG')
# select by visible text
select_element.select_by_visible_text('MG')
```

Comment: To rule the obvious out - if the menu is not disabled, you have to enable it before you can click on anything in it, even with Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the your question the website `https://www.energisa.com.br/Paginas/login.aspx` the *dropdown* menu is not with in a `Select` tag, so *Select* class won't work here.

Once the *url* is accessed, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.energisa.com.br/Paginas/login.aspx")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='estado']/div[@class='select2-container' and @id='s2id_ddlEstado']"))).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='select2-results' and @id='select2-results-1']//li/div[normalize-space()='MG']").click()
```

Comment: sorry about that my internet went down . one line of your code that I don't understand `normalize-space()` also what if i used css selectors !

Comment: If you crosscheck the element with the text `MG`, it's not an _innerHTML_, so to safeguard from blank spaces we need to use `normalize-space()`. You can use `css selectors` as well.

Comment: @ahmed.soli Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please? Thanks

Comment: @ahmed.soli This question itself is a complete _usecase_. As you have received well researched answers you shouldn't change the question as per stackoverflow standards. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown you are trying to click is not actually a `SELECT` element so you can't use the `Select` class. The `SELECT` you are trying to click is just a backing element but it's invisible so you can't interact with it.

To make this work, you will need to click the dropdown element to expose the options and then click the desired option.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#s2id_ddlEstado > a").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='select2-results-1']/li[.='MG']").click()
```

This is untested code, so you may need to add a wait...

Comment: I've already tried this approach but I got the error `the element is not clickable`

Answer (score 0):

The one which appears like a select_list is not a select_list, the purpose of this kind of select_list is, we can write into the text_field to pick up the elements from the huge list, if you type 'M', then all the options which has M will be displayed.

Write the following code, it would work.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"loadingContent")))
driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_ddlEstado").click
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='select2-results-1']//div[text()='MG']").click
```